# how to open internet explorer with powershell in window xp

Tags: windows-xp, powershell

expect to open a link in internet explorer and refresh it automatically every 5 seconds
but it can not open after try

powershell with administrator

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy remotesigned
```

powershell script

```
On Error Resume Next

Set objExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

objExplorer.Navigate "http://www.google.com"   
objExplorer.Visible = 1

Wscript.Sleep 5000

Set objDoc = objExplorer.Document

Do While True
    Wscript.Sleep 5000
    objDoc.Location.Reload(True)
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Wscript.Quit
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: That is WSH, not Powershell.

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy remotesigned
```

Is a PowerShell command, but the script is VBScript.